# Map gridded rainfall data to lat-longs and extract daily rainfall data?

Tags: raster, r, coordinates, grids-graticules, precipitation

My objective is to create a dataset, wherein for certain locations (lat-longs) I need to report daily rainfall from 1950 to 2017.

Rainfall data source: Indian Meteorological Department (IMD) daily rainfall file - in .grd format from 1950 to 2017.

Input file: a .csv file with Latitude and Longitude columns for each location of interest.

Logic: I need to map the lat-longs to a grid (size=25km^2) and extract the rainfall on each day i.e. 01/01/1950 to 31/12/1950 from a single 1950 rainfall file. Then repeat this exercise for all the years, for the same coordinates.

I need help for starters understanding how I can see rainfall data at a daily level in a dataframe of sorts i.e. deal with .GRD files with gridded rainfall data. The software I'm hoping to use is R, because my peers have previously mapped the same rainfall data to shape-files i.e. polygons of area (district/village etc.)

I'm including the code they used for reference, this is what I was trying to use but with an input file of lat-longs.

Reference code:

```
*comment:Load libraries

library(dplyr)
library(rgdal) 
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)
library(readr) 
library(bigmemory)


*comment:load shape file
shp<-readOGR(".","shapefile") # .shp extention not needed
myconn <- file("ind2017_rfp25.grd","rb") # read any binary file
a <- readBin(myconn, numeric(), n=135*129, size=4, endian = "little")

close(myconn)
##### start template creation #######
outfile<-paste("p2017_1","txt",sep=".")
cat(paste("ncols         135",
          "nrows         129",
          "xllcorner     66.5",
          "yllcorner     6.5",
          "cellsize      0.25",
          "NODATA_value  -999 \n",sep="\n"),file=outfile)
cat(a,file=outfile, append=T)

r<-raster("p2017_1.txt") ## reads the newly created ascii file as a raster
r<-flip(r,direction='y')
proj4string(r)<-proj4string(shp) ## assigns a coordinate system
##### end template creation #######

*comment:set no. of columns and rows according to resolution (info should be there in readme file)
n.cols <- 135
n.rows <- 129

binfiles <- dir(pattern = "ind")

*comment:1951 to 2017
*comment:leap year = 17 , non-leap = 49

l.years <- 8 # no. of leap years in the data
nl.years <-22  # no. of no leap years in the data
start.date <- as.Date("1951/01/01")# start date in yyyy/mm/dd
end.date <- as.Date("2017/12/31") # end date in yyyy/mm/dd
date_seq <- seq(start.date,end.date,by = "days")

celltoind <-function(x){(x %% n.cols) + n.cols*(n.rows - (x %/% n.cols) - 1)}

*comment:Get the location coordinates
vilval<-cellFromXY(r,shp)


full_prec <- matrix(ncol = (366*l.years)+(365*nl.years),
                    nrow = length(shp), data = NA)
colval <- 0

for(num in seq(binfiles))

{
  myconn<-file(binfiles[num],"rb")
  #count=1
  while (length(a <- readBin(myconn, numeric(), n=n.cols*n.rows, size=4, endian = "little")) > 0 )
  {  
    colval <- colval + 1
    a[a < (-90)]<- NA
    full_prec[,colval]<-a[celltoind(vilval)]
  }
  close(myconn)
}


full_prec<-as.data.frame(full_prec) # convert matrix to data frame

colnames(full_prec)<-date_seq # assign column names as date

prec_daily <- cbind(shp@data,full_prec) # this will assign shapefile dataframe

write_csv(prec_daily,"year_rf.csv") # write file to directory
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE. What software are you planning to use?

Comment: Hi, I was thinking R. People around me have used R before to to map rainfall data (the same source) but using shapefiles (polygons of districts/some administrative unit), however I'm trying to get them at a coordinate level.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information and the `r` tag. This way your question will be more likely to be answered. Also, have you already tried anything or do you have a strating code where you are stuck?

Comment: @MarceloVilla Thanks for the suggestion on adding the r tag! This is my first ever question. I've edited the question to include the base code my peers used.